# mapping values from one array to another

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array, arr1, which is a pd.Series array of length 1000 where some values are repeated. And I want to map every unique value in arr1 to a new value that is in a np array, arr2. I only know how to do this using a for loop:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr1 = pd.Series(np.random.choice(1000,1000, replace=True))
arr1_unq = arr1.drop_duplicates()

arr2 = np.random.choice(1000,len(arr1_unq), replace=False)
arr2_unq = np.unique(arr2)
for i in range(len(arr2)):
    arr1[arr1==arr1_unq.iloc[i]]=arr2[i]
```

How can I do this more efficiently without using a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.Series.map` should do it

```
mapping = dict(zip(arr1_unq, arr2_unq))
arr1.map(maping)
```

Comment: Yuca, your solution works. Thank you. I run unique to be able to compare arr1 after mapping with arr2, since the unique of both should be the same. And it is true.

Comment: got it, glad I could help :)